# How to choose the block that the item can be placed on?

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I would like to know how to choose the block that my TNT be placed on. Here is my code.

```
ItemStack tnt = new ItemStack(Material.TNT, 1);
```

As in `give @p tnt 1 0 {PlaceOn:emerald_block}`.

I am using Spigot for Minecraft 1.12 and Eclipse.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no way to do that via the Spigot API natively, you need to use NMS and NBT:

```
net.minecraft.server.v1_12_R1.ItemStack stack = CraftItemStack.asNMSCopy(tnt);

NBTTagList tags = (NBTTagList) stack.getTag().get("CanPlaceOn");

if (tags == null)
    tags = new NBTTagList();

tags.add(new NBTTagString("minecraft:emerald_block"));

stack.getTag().set("CanPlaceOn", tags);

ItemStack toUse = CraftItemStack.asCraftMirror(stack);
```

Comment: Thanks you very much I was looking for some sort of NBT interface

Comment: Note that `stack.getTag()` may also return null (if the stack does not have an NBT tag applied to it already).

Comment: It isnt working for me
<code>stack.getTag()</code> returns an error The method getTag() from the type ItemStack refers to the missing type NBTTagCompound

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking if you can avoid using NMS you should, and there is a pretty easy way to do this. Whenever a block is placed by a player, a BlockPlaceEvent is called by the server. If you are unsure how they work, look here: http://bukkit.gamepedia.com/Event_API_Reference.

An example of how to handle this behavior is below:

```
public void onBlockPlace(BlockPlaceEvent e) {
    if (e.getBlockPlaced().getType() == Material.TNT) {
        Material belowType = e.getBlockPlaced().getRelative(BlockFace.DOWN).getType();
        // your code here...
    }
}
```

This code allows you to check if the block that is placed is TNT, then it retrieves the type of the block directly below it.

Hope this helps!!

Comment: The block I am looking to place on is either the right or left and the player is in adventure

Comment: Way better than using NMS

Comment: In that case instead of doing e.getBlockPlaced().getRelative(BlockFace.DOWN), you would use e.getBlockAgainst()